# How can I get a 4x4 matrix from a bullet quaternion?

Tags: javascript, matrix, bullet-physics

I'm trying to make a game using JavaScript with Ammo.js ( an implementation of bullet ) and Sylvester to do my matrix maths. The problem is I don't know how to turn the WXYZ that bullet gives into the 4x4 matrix Sylvester needs.

If there is a way to just get Bullet Physics to give me the 4x4 matrix please tell me! I am completely lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.JS has a function for this based upon [this](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm) principle. BTW Matrix4x4 are represented internally as Column-Major, not sure what bullet uses.

[Three.js Matrix4x4.makeRotationFromQuaternion(Quaternion)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Matrix4.js)

```
makeRotationFromQuaternion: function ( q ) {

    var te = this.elements;

    var x = q.x, y = q.y, z = q.z, w = q.w;
    var x2 = x + x, y2 = y + y, z2 = z + z;
    var xx = x * x2, xy = x * y2, xz = x * z2;
    var yy = y * y2, yz = y * z2, zz = z * z2;
    var wx = w * x2, wy = w * y2, wz = w * z2;

    te[ 0 ] = 1 - ( yy + zz );
    te[ 4 ] = xy - wz;
    te[ 8 ] = xz + wy;

    te[ 1 ] = xy + wz;
    te[ 5 ] = 1 - ( xx + zz );
    te[ 9 ] = yz - wx;

    te[ 2 ] = xz - wy;
    te[ 6 ] = yz + wx;
    te[ 10 ] = 1 - ( xx + yy );

    // last column
    te[ 3 ] = 0;
    te[ 7 ] = 0;
    te[ 11 ] = 0;

    // bottom row
    te[ 12 ] = 0;
    te[ 13 ] = 0;
    te[ 14 ] = 0;
    te[ 15 ] = 1;

    return this;

},
```

Comment: I will try this again tomorrow - put it in my code with an error 'TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined↵  …//blockhaven.net/dev/BHJSP/blockhaven.js:1054:24)", message: "Cannot set property '0' of undefined'

Comment: You obviously can't just copy and paste it in... `this.elements` wouldn't exist if you did so. Try instantiating an array of size 16 for the variable `te`.

Comment: *facepalm* I edited it but forgot to initialise the array I just set it to return te and I just set the line to 'var te'